# Injectivity of a Morphism of Invertible Sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, schemes

Let $\mathcal{F},\mathcal{G}$ be invertible sheaves on an integral scheme $X$ and $f:\mathcal{F} \rightarrow \mathcal{G}$ be a morphism.
My question is simple. Is it the case that
$f$ is injective if and only if $f$ is induces a nonzero map at generic point?

Comment: What if $f$ is a zero morphism?

Comment: every element maps to zero...

Comment: If so, can it be *non-zero* at generic point?

Comment: Yes, you're alght

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question comes down to: If $R$ is an integral domain and $a \in R$, is it true that $a : R \to R$ is injective iff $a \neq 0$ in $\mathrm{Quot}(R)$? Sure, and we may also add $a \neq 0$ in $R$ here.

Comment: Dear @Martin, I really like the very simplified way you answer questions. This helps a lot. Cheers.